# Which database to use for making a small inventory management system?

Tags: database, sql-server

I, want to make a small business inventory management system application in  java ,for windows 7,8,10  . I have used sql server express ( but it has a limit of 10 gb) and a little of mysql but i know there are other products like postgresql, sqlite and mongodb. Which should be best to use?

I am confused because of the limit of 10 gb in sql server (should i say to customer that you have to delete the data after it exceeds 10gb ), many saying mysql in bad in performance and stability. Any help would be great.

Comment: There is no-one who might want to buy your little Java app who will need more that 10GB to store information on their inventory! If you had an organisation that big, they would be using the inventory managment features of their preferred ERP system. Note also, if you use an appropriatey tiered architecture, you would be able to offer multiple DB options.

Comment: You should provide more details about your requirements and constraints for us to provide a good recommendation.  One-off project or an app to resold to many customers? Networked or run over a local network with multiple users? Is cloud-based deployment a possible need? "Performance and stability" have no meaning without the context of your needs and environment. 10 gig limit should be the least of your concerns, the last of many criteria rather than the only criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 GB is a huge size for a database. Are you sure that your database will be so large?

If you're familiar to programming in Java, you could use [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)). I know that OpenConcerto which is an accounting/invoicing/inventory management software uses this format for local installations of the software, whilst for client-server installations it uses PostgreSQL. This project is open source so that you could (at least in theory) adapt it to your needs.

Some databases are more oriented toward local use, like sqlite for instance.
Others are more oriented to server-client mode, like MySQL and PostgreSQL.

For inventory management you could have a look at [Kexi](http://www.kexi-project.org/), which is using an sqlite database for each inventory that you create. It's however not written in Java.

It would be nice knowing more about your project. If it's for personal use or if you plan selling your software. If concurrent access of several users are planned, in reading and/or in writing and more technical details.

Comment: Concurrent 2 users , plan to sell, i don't know the size of the database that will be going to. But i don't want to tell customer that you can only store 10gb of data. Customer also doesn't know how much data is he going to use. Software is for jewellery shop with 2 persons handling it.

Comment: (A) I agree with the suggestion to try the H2 database. The project author has many years of experience in building database systems. Runs in pure Java. Quite powerful in terms of features. Can be used either embedded in an app or as a server. (B) For developing the user-interface and application-server I highly recommend [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com) for writing your app in pure Java but automagically rendered in web browser using standard web technologies.

Comment: @BasilBourque there was a bug "Some problems have been found with right outer join. Internally, it is converted to left outer join, which does not always produce the same results as other databases when used in combination with other joins. This problem is fixed in H2 version 1.3." After seeing this how can i use it and assume its reliable in other features also.

Comment: @OuzoPower there was a bug "Some problems have been found with right outer join. Internally, it is converted to left outer join, which does not always produce the same results as other databases when used in combination with other joins. This problem is fixed in H2 version 1.3." After seeing this how can i use it and assume its reliable in other features also.

Comment: The bug is officially in the page http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html

Comment: @Shreyansjain “…how can I use it and assume it’s reliable” — *Never assume a library or tool is reliable.* **Test it!**  Every significant piece of software has bugs, issues, and limitations. Compounded further by an always-changing environment of OS, JVM, drivers, libraries, and such.   Write and use unit tests, integration tests, acceptance tests, assertion tests. Test even the most basic things such as rounding a nickel to the penny (rounding 0.05 should result in 0.05), which is how I was one of the first to discover Apple shipped a faulty Rosetta code translator to millions of Mac users.

Comment: @BasilBourque Again thanks for advice.

Comment: @Shreyansjain Bugs are another reason to use open-source products for critical parts of your system such as a database engine. The bugs are openly and immediately known and discussed. Anyone interested can study the source to investigate. With proprietary products, bugs are sometimes revealed and sometimes not, and certainly not revealed immediately. You have to wait on the magnanimity  of the company managers to learn of the problem, the cause, and possible solutions. Some licenses even prevent you from publicly discussing bugs or performance issues.

Comment: @BasilBourque again thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Shreyans: Which storage-hungry ressources could require 10 GB?
One of my customers is a jeweler. The really nice pics on his webshop are about 700 KB each.
If we except the other data in the database, a small calculation shows that even if you store your pictures as BLOB (which is often a bad idea) a 10GB database can store about almost 15,000 BLOBs with size 700 Ko. Or, alternatively, almost 42,000 paths to external ressources.
I myself have a MySQL DB with 281 products.
The products table, with 46 columns per product is 192 KB.
The size of the DB is below one half MB, i.e. < 0.0005 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Several databases can be used to make a small inventory management system. You can use Kexi leverages SQLite database for each inventory you create.

You can also use the following database when you plan to make an inventory management system no matter if it's small or big:

```
• MYSQL database 
• Microsoft SQL-server database
• Microsoft Access database
• Excel file or even you can use Oracle database
```

When you plan to make an inventory management system, you should first check out the size of the business and then you will be able to decide what size of the database and which database you should use to making a strong and scalable inventory management system. For more information you can read the  article - https://i-verve.com/blog/inventory-management-systems